# Set Radio Button Value

Tags: java, android

```
RadioGroup genderGroup;
RadioButton genderType;
genderGroup = findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
int id = genderGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
genderType = findViewById(id);
```

How to set a value to a radio button which is inside a radio group.
genderType get a value but i have no clue how to set a radio button as checked

The below code is the code used in the xml file

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="63dp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editTextUsername"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView6">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButtonMale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Male" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButtonFemale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Female" />
    </RadioGroup>
```

What I'm trying to do is to save a checked radio button and later to update it or retrieve it from the database and display it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you get `RadioButton` id which is checked by using `getCheckedRadioButtonId()`, you can compare it with 2 exist `RadioButton` and determine which is real checked and save to database:

```
int genderValue = 0;
if (id == R.id.radioButtonMale){
    genderValue = 0;
}else{
    genderValue = 1;
}

//then you can save genderValue to database

//get value from database
int genderValue = ....; //get from database
if (genderValue == 0){
    radioGroup.check(R.id.radioButtonMale);
}else{
    radioGroup.check(R.id.radioButtonFemale);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `switch` in something like this:

```
   RadioGroup  mRadioGroup = findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
   RadioButton mRadioBtnmale =  findViewById(R.id.radioButtonMale);
   RadioButton mRadioBtnfemale =  findViewById(R.id.radioButtonFemale);

   mRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            switch (checkedId){
                  case R.id.radioButtonMale:
                      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Male selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
                  case R.id.radioButtonFemale:
                      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"FeMale selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
       }
   });
```

If you want set the values explicitly you could do like this, however you logic should decide which one to checked and unchecked:

```
   mRadioBtnmale.setChecked(true);
   mRadioBtnmale.setChecked(false);
```

Answer (score -1):

> Try This Code--- Main.xml

```
        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioSex"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioMale"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/radio_male" 
                android:checked="true" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioFemale"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/radio_female" />

        </RadioGroup>
```

> Activity.java

```
        private RadioGroup radioSexGroup;
        private RadioButton radioSexButton;
        private Button btnDisplay;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        addListenerOnButton();
        }

        public void addListenerOnButton() {
        radioSexGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioSex);
        btnDisplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDisplay);

        btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        // get selected radio button from radioGroup
        int selectedId = radioSexGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        // find the radiobutton by returned id
        radioSexButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

        Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this, radioSexButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        });
        }
```